# The field "$name" must be an accumulator object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query and when I use a [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) a error shows "the field "$name must be an accumulator object", if if remove the filed "$name" all works well and i have tried to use only "name" instead of "$name" and the error continues.

```
   User.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        "storeKey": req.body.store        
      }
  },
  {
      $group: {
          "_id": "$_id",          
          "name": "$name",              
          "count": {
              "$sum": 1
          },
          "totalValue": {
              "$sum": "$value"
          }      
      }
  },
  {
    $sort: sort
  },
  {
     $skip: req.body.limit * req.body.page
  },
  {
     $limit: req.body.limit
  }
])...
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There are some aggregation operators that can only be used in [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation and named as [`$group accumulators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation-group/)

Just as you used [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) here you have to use for the `name` key as well

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": "$_id",
  "name": { "$first": "$name" },  //$first accumulator
  "count": { "$sum": 1 },  //$sum accumulator
  "totalValue": { "$sum": "$value" }  //$sum accumulator
}}
```

Accumulator is like array of Elements its Accumulates as Array.
$first -> gives 1st name that goes in the group of names

Example:
so if you have `$_id` same but different name `["Darik","John"]`
specifying `$first` will give Darik & similarly `$last` will give John

Comment: It works! but i read the documentation about `$first` and i didn't understand anything about how to use and why

Comment: `$first` will always give you the first document after applying the `$group` stage. Similarly `$last` will give you the last document.

Comment: what to do if we want all values. @Ashh

Comment: Use `$$ROOT` @,mufazmi

Comment: And, what if I have a field like UserRole, where I want to get a value in the group, based at a condition. In this example, get the highest hierarchy user.

Answer (score -5):

```
db.faq_feedback.aggregate({ 
   $lookup:{ 
      "from":"faq",
      "localField":"question_id",
      "foreignField":"_id",
      "as":"faq"
   }
},
{ 
   $unwind:"$faq"
},

{ 
   $project:{ 
      "question_id":1,
      "lang":"$faq.lang",
      "feedback":"$faq.feedback",
      "question":"$faq.question",
      "yes":{ 
         "$cond":[ 
            { 
               "$eq":[ 
                  "$feedback",
                  "yes"
               ]
            },
            1,
            0
         ]
      },
      "no":{ 
         "$cond":[ 
            { 
               "$eq":[ 
                  "$feedback",
                  "no"
               ]
            },
            1,
            0
         ]
      }
   }
},

{ 
   $group:{ 
      "_id":"$question_id",

      "yes":{ 
         "$sum":"$yes"
      },
      "no":{ 
         "$sum":"$no"
      },
      "question":{"$first":"$question"},
      "lang":{"$first":"$lang"}
   }
},
{ 
   $limit:10000
},
{ 
   $skip:0
})
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score -6):

```
$group: {
    _id:"$_id", 
    "name" :{ $last: '$name' }, 
    "count" : { $sum: 1 }, 
    "totalValue": { "$sum": "$value" }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain your answer?