# How to aggregate the values of a field into an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's take a collection named `values` which contains the following documents.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "value1", "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "value1", "x" : 2, "y" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "value1", "z" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "value1", "z" : 20 }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "value2", "x" : 8, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "value2", "x" : 8, "y" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 7, "name" : "value2", "z" : 15 }
```

Here, if I query based on `name`, take `value1`, then I should get the following single document.

```
{ "name" : "value1", "x" : [ 1, 2 ], "y" : [ 2, 2 ], "z" : [ 10, 20 ] }
```

I think this has something to do with aggregation. But I have no idea how to do it. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregtion

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "value1"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      x: {
        "$push": "$x"
      },
      y: {
        "$push": "$y"
      },
      z: {
        "$push": "$z"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5wJ304uBksG)

Comment: Is it possible to add a `name` field to the resulting document?

Comment: Yeah. But what if I match the documents using multiple common fields like `name` and I want to include them in the resulting document?

Comment: I got it. If we use `$first`, we can still have the fields we want.

Comment: @L.ShaneJohnPaulNewton Yes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54440636/the-field-name-must-be-an-accumulator-object